# Can/should a logical multi-class classification anomaly detection system be described as "unsupervised machine learning"?

Tags: feature-selection, multiclass-classification, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, outlier

I would like to ensure that my use of terminology is accurate. My question is: what terminology should I be using in this case?

The system I am building assigns classes (-1, 0, +1) to observations with continuous metrics that are scored as a Boolean (0, 1) if their absolute value exceeds univariable outlier cutoffs defined by the entire dataset. Boolean logical is applied to the resultant features to classify observations. For example:

```
if (boolean_feature1 == True) & (boolean_feature2 == True):
  observation_class = 1
elif (boolean_feature1 == True) | (boolean_feature2 == True):
  observation_class = 0
else
  observation_class = -1
```

Can this logical multi-class classification anomaly detection system be described as "unsupervised machine learning" or there another succint descriptor that should be used instead? Can feature derivation based on sample statistics be considered "learning", and can hardcoded decision logical be considered machine intelligence?

Comment: Why do you consider this to be anomaly-detection ?

Comment: boolean_feature1 is actually = data.feature > threshold kind of expression? If so, how are the thresholds set?